# Hadoop Mapreduce tasktrackers keep ignoring HADOOP_CLASSPATH. Zookeeper trying to connect to localhost rather than cluster address

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera, apache-zookeeper

I have a Hadoop cluster (Cloudera CDH4.2) with 5 datanodes. I'm trying to run a MapReduce job which creates an `HBaseConfiguration` object. The tasktracker attempts fail, because they're trying to connect to `localhost:2181` rather than the address of the actual zookeeper installation.

I'm aware that this is because the tasktrackers are not being supplied with the correct classpath containing the hbase configuration. However, if I run the job like so:

```
HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`/usr/bin/hbase classpath` hadoop jar myjar.jar
```

The documentation indicates this should solve the problem. The first entry in `hbase classpath` is `/usr/lib/hbase/conf` which is a symlink to `/etc/hbase/conf`, so in theory, this should add the hbase configuration into the `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` variable.

However, the logs from the tasktracker show this:

```
2013-08-14 12:47:24,308 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.class.path=<output of `hadoop classpath`>
....
2013-08-14 12:47:24,309 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
.....
2013-08-14 12:47:24,328 WARN org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

So, for some reason, the tasktrackers are completely ignoring my effort to set `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` to `hbase classpath`. The documentation (http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/package-summary.html#classpath) states this should just work. What's wrong?

I'm aware I could work around this by explicitly specifying the zookeeper quorum address in the jar code, but I need this jar to be portable, and pick up the local configuration without recompiling, so I don't see hard coding the address as a viable option.

Comment: try these steps:  1) make sure the hbase-site.xml contains correct Zk quorum; 2) `export HADOOP_CONF_DIR="$HADOOP_HOME/conf"`  3) `export HBASE_CONF_DIR="$HBASE_HOME/conf"`

Comment: (1) the hbase-site.xml contains the correct `hbase.zookeeper.quorum` value and is the same file across the whole cluster. (2) and (3) made no difference (assuming I'm setting these on the client, rather than the cluster nodes). Same classpath in the tasktracker logs. Same output.

Comment: @growse: I am having the same issue, and I was wondering if you found the solution. If so, would you mind to share it?

Comment: No - I ended up specifying the zk address manually.

Comment: The same problem is for me. Each TT node has "hbase gataway role" with deployed "client configuration". But When code submits job which uses hbase, /etc/hbase/conf is ont in classpath :(

Answer (score 0):

if you made java programming:

```
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "server1,server2,server3");    
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
```

if you used command:add -Dhbase.zookeeper.quorum

```
sudo hadoop jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.3.0-1.cdh4.3.0.p0.22/lib/hbase/hbase.jar rowcounter -Dhbase.zookeeper.quorum=server1,server2,server3 hly_temp
```